# Problem connecting to MySQL with eRuby

Tags: mysql, ruby, linux, fedora, eruby

I'm having a problem connecting my eRuby scripts to my MySQL database.

I've written a short test script just to work out the initial connection bugs:

```
<%

require 'mysql'

begin
     dbh = Mysql::new("localhost", "test", "wahssf", "amg")
rescue Mysql::Error => e
     print "Error code: #{e.errno}<br />"
     print "Error message: #{e.error}<br />"
     print "Error SQLSTATE: #{e.sqlstate}" if e.respond_to?("sqlstate")
ensure
     dbh.close if dbh
end

%>
```

Now, as long as I keep the connection parameters as gibberish ("test", "wahssf", "amg"), the script defaults to the `Mysql::Error` class and prints the following to the browser:

```
Error code: 1045
Error message: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Error SQLSTATE: 28000
```

However, once I put in REAL connection values and reload the page, the script fails (for some reason?) and I get an `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`.

I have absolutely no idea what the problem is.  As long as the username/password combination is wrong, the script "works" but obviously doesn't connect, but as soon as I give it the proper credentials, it fails.

Any ideas?

Also, what's worth mentioning: When I execute this script by typing it in line by line via `irb` on the command prompt, it works.  It only *seems* to be an issue in eRuby.

Vitals:
Apache 2.2.8 running on Fedora Core 7
MySQL 5.0.* (gem `mysql` version 2.8.1)
Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Is there anything in the server logs? You could also try running this code from the command line and see if any errors are output there.

Comment: `/ruby.rhtml:7:in 'close': wrong argument type Mysql (expected Struct) (TypeError)`

I tried adding a query() method to dbh as well, with the same error being returned.

Comment: What if you say `dbh = Mysql.new` instead of `dbh = Mysql::new`?

Comment: The same error is reported to the logs as before.  Why would it expect a type OTHER than Mysql for the methods that are part of the Mysql class?  And what does type Struct refer to?  I'm completely at a loss here :\

Answer (score 0):

if message is `Access denied` check the username, password, host, and port!